# change object but not reference c#

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, reference

*MainClass* has an object of Data. 
To create *Class2* i have to give *MainData* to *Class2*.
In Class2 there is a Load function that loads an Data object from a file. So the MainData object should be changed to the new object.

In Class2 the Data object is Binded to an control.

This is a simple example:

```
class MainClass {
    public Data Maindata { get; set; }
    private Class2 cla;
    public MainClass() {
        Maindata = new Data();
        Maindata.Name = "Maindata";
        Console.WriteLine("Class1.MainData = " + Maindata.Name);
        cla = new Class2(Maindata);
        //Here should Maindata.Name = newData
        Console.WriteLine("Class1.MainData = " + Maindata.Name);
    }
}
class Class2 {
    public Data data { get; set; }
    public Class2(Data maindata) {
        data = maindata;
        changeData();
        Console.WriteLine("Class2.Data = "+data.Name);
    }

    private void changeData() {
        Data test = new Data();
        test.Name = "newData";
        data = test;
    }
}
class Data {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I know you can just change it by doing data.Name = "newData";
But if Data has more than 100 properties it's Overkill;

Comment: Why would you pass mainData is your goal is to create a new Data anyway two lines after? Anyway, what you are looking for is the "out" keyword.

Comment: Because there is a load function that deserialises a file to a Data object. The Data object has more than 100 properties. And the Data object in Class2 is Binded to controls in the view.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the existing object instead of creating a new one:

```
private void changeData() {
    data.Name = "newData";
}
```

If you want to create a new object, you would need to make `Class2` aware of `MainClass` so that it can change the property:

```
public Class2(MainClass main) {
    changeData();
    main.Maindata = data;
    Console.WriteLine("Class2.Data = "+data.Name);
}
```

and call it using the `MainClass` object instead of the `Maindata` object:

```
cla = new Class2(this);
```

Comment: Yes i thought about that but isn't there a beter way to do this. Doesn't this use alot of memory/space?

Comment: @Sam_vdd - no it doesn't, it passes a pointer to the `MainClass` object, it's not making a copy. So it's no different in memory terms to passing the pointer to a `Data` object. But even if it did take up more space, don't be tempted to optimise too early - get it working first, only then can you identify what needs optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

While I would question the "why the hell are you doing this?", the answer to your specific question as to how to pass the newly created object inside the constructor toward the method calling it would be done with the "out" keyword:

```
public Class2(out Data maindata) 
{
    changeData();
    maindata = data;
}

private Data changeData()
{
    Data test = new Data();
    test.Name = "newData";
    data = test;
}
```

Comment: Because there is a load function that deserialises a file to a Data object. The Data object has more than 100 properties. And the Data object in Class2 is Binded to controls in the view.

Answer (score 0):

All this is doing:

```
private void changeData() {
    Data test = new Data();
    test.Name = "newData";
    data = test; //assign the new object to the property data in Class2
}
```

The act of assigning to the `Class2` property `data` has nothing to do with `MainClass`'s `MainData` property.

This code would affect the shared `Data` object:

```
private void changeData() {
    data.Name = "newData";
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
class Class2 {
    public Data data { get; set; }
    public Class2(ref Data maindata) {
        data = maindata;
        changeData();
        maindata = data;
        Console.WriteLine("Class2.Data = "+data.Name);
    }

    private void changeData() {
        Data test = new Data();
        test.Name = "newData";
        data = test;
    }
}
```

Through the ref-Keyword `MainData` will apply the changes of `maindata`.

Comment: Ok but how can i get the ref Data mainData from another function?